# How can I install an Epson iPrint App?

Tags: applications

I have a 10.1 inch Android Tablet (4.4 Operating System).
I want to install an Epson iPrint App so that I can use an
Epson wireless printer. I keep being getting the message
that there is insufficient storage available to install
the iPrint App.The App contains 26.4 MB.I have already
uninstalled 80MBs worth of Apps but the Tablet still won't
accept the iPrint App.The Tablet has a 32GB microSD storage
card.What can I do?

Comment: It is not relevant to us the size of the screen of your tablet. You may remove it and please mention the device name because that is important here (to easily ascertain the size of internal storage). Also, checkout the wiki of [tag:insufficient-memory] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Android seems to need more space than the app requires to download and install it - as a rule of thumb on my older devices I cleared 4x what was required to get app installs to work.  However on newer devices (including my Nexus 7) most Google applications (including Play Store) won't let the device get below approx 500MB.

Things to try are

- For apps which store a lot of offline content set them to use external storage (this may not always be available).  For example in Google Play Music - Hamburger > Settings > Storage Location > External
- Clear the cache of an app - Go to Settings > Apps > Overflow Menu > Sort By Size and look for the largest app you're not expecting to be using much space (e.g. Facebook, Instagram, or Twitter) - try clearing the cache.
- Remove some downloaded content (e.g. video, music) from the tablet (e.g. video you've downloaded from BBC iPlayer or Amazon Instant Video)

When you have sufficient space to install apps again, Disk Usage https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage is a handy app to have installed - it can identify apps which are using way more storage than you expect (e.g. offline video from an app you've long since removed).